# Using vuplex with openxr in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, webview, openxr

I am currently working on a mixed reality project using unity and xr interaction toolkit. I want to use Vuplex to show the webpages and to interact with webpages. But I am facing an issue, that is Vuplex and OpenXR couldn't be used together may be. Because when I build and run it in my Quest 3 I got to see the error message on the CanvasWebViewPrefab that net::ERR_CACHE_MISS. Even https://www.google.com is not being loaded too.
While if I am using Vuplex with oculus enabled it's working fine.

Please suggest me some ideas to make Vuplex work with OpenXR.

I have tried adding permissions to the android manifest file but still it's not working.
Tried asking chatGPT(4).